# Working with Laravel Passport scopes: typical workflow

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

Perhaps such an obvious question, but requesting an access token with **Password Grant Type** and `'scope' => '*'`, using Laravel 5.3 + Passport always returns the all-access token, no matter the user who requested it.

So... Where does the filtering / limiting validation logic usually reside? 
Can you please specify the common workflow in this situations?

Comment: Good question. You can make internal grouped routes inside protected routes, and each is independent of the token. As each user have it's access permissions, each group will have a specific middleware that checks it, comparing the user access permission id (it depends on how it is stored in the database) and the id of the internal grouped routes (administrator routes, for example).